# gradle resolve the dependencies if the artifact is not found then build the dependent and upload the artifact

Tags: gradle, build-automation, dependency-management, build.gradle

During configuration cycle of gradle where it tries to resolve the dependencies is there a way where I can add custom task/plugin such as to build the dependent project(details of svn path of the dependent project is provide thru ext properties) if the artifact is not found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a built-in feature for this. It may be possible to implement this yourself, but it won't be easy. To get started, have a look at https://github.com/pniederw/elastic-deps, which is a proof-of-concept to replace project dependencies with external dependencies if they aren't available locally.

PS: Configurations are resolved when their artifacts are first requested, which typically happens in the execution phase (not configuration phase).

Answer (score 0):

I had a need for the same feature. Getting it to work with gradle was a cinch. The hard part was figuring out how Android Studio syncs the gradle files. Without a successful sync, the IDE will complain it can't find any dependencies. At any rate, I figured it out, here is my solution to make it work with gradle and Android Studio.

https://gist.github.com/vangorra/c1383c355ce8fe56adf8

It essentially boils down to defining the project in settings.gradle:

```
include 'library'
project(':library').projectDir = file('../Library/library')
```

Then you have to use a one-liner with options closure for your dependency:

```
compile ( project(':library').projectDir.exists() ? project(':library'): 'Library:library:unspecified@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```